# How to dynamically use icon in a React app based on a string value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following setup, and it is working.

```
import * as Icon1 from 'images/img1.svg'
import * as Icon2 from 'images/img2.svg'

const Foo = () => {
    return (<>
        <AComponent icon={Icon1}/>
    </>)
}
```

Now the task is to have the icon dynamically determined from a string value, so I try:

```
import * as Icon1 from 'images/img1.svg'
import * as Icon2 from 'images/img2.svg'

const Foo = () => {

    const theIcon = 'Icon1' // can be 'Icon2' at other times

    return (<>
        <AComponent icon={eval(theIcon)}/>
    </>)
}
```

This gives Runtime Error: *ReferenceError: Icon1 is not defined.*

So it would look like React has correctly identify Icon1 as a variable name, but it has failed to locate it from the imports.

Also it is possible to have `theIcon = 'img1.svg'`, if need be. Just really would like to achieve the goal of dynamically assigning this icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @messerbill suggests, you can write a method for it which returns the correct value based on the given parameter.
The method can contain either a 'switch case' or 'if else statements'.
Also you can write an object with values based on icons you have imported:

```
import * as Icon1 from 'images/img1.svg';
import * as Icon2 from 'images/img2.svg';

const availableIcons = {
 icon1: Icon1,
 icon2: Icon2,
};

const getCorrectIcon:(givenName) => {
    return availableIcons[givenName];
}

const Foo = ({ iconName }) => {

   const theIcon = getCorrectIcon(iconName) ?? defaultValue;

   return (<>
       <AComponent icon={theIcon}/>
   </>)
}
```

Comment: A mix of this answer and the other one would be ideal imho. I'd avoid to use `eval` at all

Comment: thank you so much everyone. I take on all your valuable suggestions and have my issue solved. please if you can change the last line here to `return (<><AComponent icon={theIcon}/></>)` (like @messerbill suggested) and I'd be happy to mark this as answer. thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

It's simple:

```
<AComponent icon={stringVariable === "icon1" ? Icon1 : Icon2}/>
```

Comment: Of course you can also refer to a method if you need to have more than 2 options: `<AComponent icon={getIcon(stringVariable)}/>`

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer. However the question description was a simplified version. We do have around 20 icons in the full program.

Comment: @messerbill I couldn't seem to get over the hurdle that the icons are now imported entities. Could you please give a full code example of the getIcon() function you suggested? many thanks

Comment: @Steve the other answer has a good example of a mapping-object. I'd mix this implementation here and the other one. Try not to use `eval` at all